# Graph referrals by social networks over time

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to use Google analytics or Google Data Studio (or both) to create a Time Series graph that shows the count of referrals by social network over time.

As you can see in the picture, there is a color for each social network, and the lines of the graph allow me to compare how much traffic is coming from each network.

It seems like this should be simple, but I'm obviously missing something.

**Picture of the graph I want to create**:
[image: Picture of the graph I want to create]

Answer (score 0):

Standard Google Data Studio Time Series graph.

- ***Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Breakdown Dimension*** - `Source / Medium`  (to see only social networks, make a filter to only include the sources you want)
- ***Metric***: `Entrances` or `Sessions`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "social network" as your breakdown dimension, instead of source/medium (which might get you too many options that aren't granular enough). Just keep in mind that with some GA/Data Studio accounts, there are two dimensions called "social network." One works and one doesn't. No idea why that is.

Answer (score 0):

One way that it can be achieved is by using a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart with a [Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144):

### 1) Time Series Chart

- ***Data Source***: Google Analytics
- ***Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Breakdown Dimension***: `Source`
- ***Metric***: `Sessions`
- ***(Optional)***: Optional Metrics

### 2) Control

- ***Type***: Drop-down list
- ***Dimension***: `Medium`
- ***Default Selection***: `referral`

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4cb71b54-328a-4bbd-b55c-715c299585e2) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]